# Why the result of Integer.toBinaryString for short type argument includes 32 bits?

Tags: java

I learned a short type variable is a 16-bit signed integer, but

```
    short n = -1;

    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(n));
```

outputs:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

The result includes 32 bits, why?

Comment: Because the actual argument value is always an int, by the method signature and promotion rules, and secondarily because it's a method in the Integer class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that `Integer` represents a 32 bit type and `toBinaryString()` takes an `int` argument. Your `short` argument is promoted to an `int` before calling the method.

Comment: Is there any API can print short type variable in binary?

Comment: Sure, just use `Integer.toBinaryString()` and take the last (up to) 16 binary digits.

Comment: Somebody says the short type integer is evaluated in 32-bit in the JVM, Is he said right?

Comment: Yes, that's right, but that fact doesn't have anything to do with your question.

Comment: @GregHewgill or, to make it more clear to the reader, take the last `Short.SIZE` digits :)

Comment: @GregHewgill This is the reason he gave me for my question.

Comment: The internals of how the JVM works with integers doesn't matter. What matters is that the `toBinaryString()` method takes an `int` parameter, and that method cannot determine whether you pass it an `int`, or a `short` that is promoted to an `int`. All it sees is "an `int` value of `-1`" and prints out 32 binary digits, because that's what it is designed to do.

Comment: @owlstead How to use Short.SIZE in my question program?

Comment: I found out that `toBinaryString()` will return the shortest representation, so without zero padding. This makes life more difficult, so I added an answer that returns the exact amount of digits specified. You can then use Short.SIZE in the call of that method.

Answer (score 2):

your `short` is implicitly cast to an `int` when you call `toBinaryString()`:

```
public static String Integer.toBinaryString(int i)
```

Answer (score 1):

To print the lower 16-bit you can use.

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(n & 0xFFFF));
```

For zero patting.

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0x10000 + (n & 0xFFFF)).substring(1));
```

Comment: Correct of course, except that if it is a positive number, the result won't contain zero padding for the most significant bits.